# running multiple instances of ehcache on the same machine with a single config

Tags: java, ehcache

im trying to set up a replicated ehcache that can run both over a local network and on the same machine. my current config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<!-- clustering -->
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1, multicastGroupPort=4446, multicastPacketTimeToLive=255"
        propertySeparator=","/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostname=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"
        propertySeparator=","/>

<cache name="demo-cache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="0"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="0"
       eternal="true"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       maxBytesLocalHeap="10M"
       diskPersistent="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="5"
       clearOnFlush="false">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true "/>
</cache>
```

this works across different machines, but does not work with multiple instances on the same machine.
i know that playing around with the peer listener factory port (40001, 40002 etc) will probbaly work, but im hoping that there's a configuration that will "just work" in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer is i cant. the jgroups support in ehcache 2.5 doesnt work and with RMI each node needs its own port.

what i eventually did was create the conf from the xml, parse the port out of the properties field for the peer listener factory and run a loop that creates ServerSockets until it finds a free port (meaning the ServerSocket constructor doesnt throw an exception) and uses that.
its ugly but it works

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old topic but I also had similar problem. In such case I used configuration like below:

```
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"     properties="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with hostname=localhost y port=0 in cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory. It should work.

If you set up 0 for port, RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory will allocate differents random ports intead of the same.

Comment: Hi! Could you add a little bit of an explanation to your answer to make it more useful for others?

Comment: If you set up 0 for port, RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory will allocate differents random ports intead of the same.